# Option page not updating multiple records in settings api

Tags: wordpress

Hi i am new to wordpress plugin development. i have issues with settings api. please help if you can.

Below is my problem.

The problem i am facing is the last record which is link it is updating in database but the title text is not updating in database.

So please help me find solution. Thank you.

```
 function load_plugin() {

  add_settings_section('plugin_main', '<h1>Ticker Settings</h1>', 'plugin_section_text', 'plugin');
  add_settings_field('plugin_text_string', 'Title text', 'plugin_setting_string', 'plugin', 'plugin_main');
  add_settings_field('post_title_link', 'Link', 'plugin_link_setting', 'plugin', 'plugin_main');

  register_setting('plugin_options', 'plugin_options');
  register_setting('post_title_link', 'post_title_link');
}

function plugin_section_text() {
   echo '<p>Change your post ticker title and give link to.</p>';
}

function plugin_setting_string() {
  echo "<input id='plugin_text_string' name='plugin_options' size='40' 
type='text' value='" . get_option('plugin_options') . "' />";
}

function plugin_link_setting() {
echo "<input id='post_title_link' name='post_title_link' size='40'
      type='text' value='" . get_option('post_title_link') . "' />";
}

add_action('admin_init', 'load_plugin');
function post_ticker_setting() {
?>
<div class="wrap">
    <form action="options.php" method="post">
        <?php
        settings_fields('plugin_options');
        settings_fields('post_title_link');
        do_settings_sections('plugin');
        ?>
        <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Save Changes'); ?>" />
    </form>
</div>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to register all settings with register_setting (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_field). The register_setting lines you show don't correspond to your fields.
Also sections should be declared after the fields are registered (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_setting) 
In your code, the following lines

```
        <?php
    settings_fields('plugin_options');
    settings_fields('post_title_link');
    do_settings_sections('plugin');
    ?>
```

don't correspond to the declarations above:

```
add_settings_section('plugin_main', ...
add_settings_field('plugin_text_string', ...
add_settings_field('post_title_link', ...
```

Only the 'post_title_link' has the same name. Which is probably why it is the only one updating.